# InfusionSoft legacy xml-rpc API access token expiring frequently

Tags: api, google-apps-script, access-token, xml-rpc, infusionsoft

I am working with the leagacy xml-rpc API of InfusionSoft to just update a few contact details of a contact like email and opt-out reason etc.

I am using google apps script to achieve that as the data with contact-id is available there as a list. Though, it is part of a larger project where these contacts are being retrieved from other sources.

I often see that I get a response 401 (Not Authorized) message in response to the requests being made. It requires regenerating the access token to get those requests through.

Is there any way, to have never-expiring token or some maximum time limit for that? as the client needs to regenerate token often to get that data updated.

The script needs to run daily for all new contacts available on the list, and no other user is involved.

For the time being, I am sharing the sample code retrieving contact details and that works fine when new token is generated the same day.

```
function infusionTry()
{
  var KEY = APIKEY;
  var INF_TOKEN = ACCESS_TOKEN;
  var url = "https://api.infusionsoft.com/crm/xmlrpc/v1?access_token=" + INF_TOKEN;
  var payload = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("ReqData").getRawContent();
  payload = payload.replace("{privateKey}",KEY);
  payload = payload.replace("{contactIDNumber}",666486);
  var params = {
    method: "post",
    contentType : "application/xml",
    payload : payload,    
    muteHttpExceptions: true
  };
  var resp = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
  Logger.log(resp.getResponseCode());
  Logger.log(resp.getContentText());
}
```

---

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dealing with the legacy authentication, there is a different request URL to connect to the API.

The URL that you referenced:

```
var url = "https://api.infusionsoft.com/crm/xmlrpc/v1?access_token=" + INF_TOKEN;
```

is used for accessing the API via OAuth.

when using the legacy API with the Infusionsoft API Key, you should make calls to the following URL:

```
var url = "https://APPNAME.infusionsoft.com:443/api/xmlrpc";
```

where APPNAME is the Infusionsoft Application Name (subdomain) for your account.

The Infusionsoft API key does not expire (but it may be changed by a user inside of Infusionsoft on demand).

In regard to the OAuth flow, here is a bit more information.

The access token expires every 24 hours.

The process will provide you two tokens.

The **refresh token** lives for 90 days and is used to generate an access token.

Infusionsoft just announced that the refresh token will expire every 90 days, which means you must refresh your script more frequently than that if you would like to skip a manual authorization to reset the token.

The **access token** lives for 24 hours and is used to make API calls.

So the overall process is:

1. User must give initial permission. (User will actually login and confirm permission.)
2. Your script should safely store the refresh token for the "long term" (perhaps in the database) and store/cache the access token for "short term"/immediate (perhaps in the session) use.
3. Before the access token expires your script will need to call Infusionsoft with the refresh token and Infusionsoft will respond with both a new refresh token AND a new access token. Once you make this call, the OLD refresh token and access token both become invalid and cannot be used again.
4. Repeat from Step 2.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying about that.

May be I was unclear in the initial question or I am unclear now about what you are saying,

1. Isn't the process you described, about the oauth workflow?

2. I am using the legacy API (mentioned in the subject) where api key + token is generated from their website and used in the calls to the API ( as is the case with plenty of API's). Is there any refresh token data offered from their developer website / front end?

Comment: @FiTeach I missed the legacy part. I will update the answer.

Comment: It seems to work. Thanks a lot. I must have confused myself from their documentation.